# Azure powershell web backup progress

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have an azure web application and database that I want to backup using a powershell script. I have the script to backup the app and database already finish and working, but I want the script to tell me when the backup is complete. I know about the Recovery Services Vault and the wait-azurermrecoveryservicesbackupjob cmdlet but they only seem to work for azure virtual machines. Does any one have any ideas on how this can be accomplished.